# two machines direct link + connection through switch

Tags: routing, home-networking, gateway

I have been trying for the last couple of days to get a setup like the one below working.

I have 
a server Ubuntu 16.04 with two network cards, 1 1Gbit, 1 10Gbit
a windows machine windows 10 with two network cards, 1 1Gbit, 1 10Gbit

I can ping from the windows machine to the servers 192.168.1.200 address, but not to the 192.168.0.200. The windows machine can also access the internet just fine.

from the server I can ping the windows machine, i.e. 192.168.1.49.
I can also ping some of the hosts in the 192.168.0.0/24 net, but not the default gateway. The server also have no connection to the internet.

So my question is, how do I get this to work, it seems fairly simple - I want the two machines to communicate all 192.168.1.0/24 traffic directly via the fast 10Gbs link and everything else should go via the default gateway.

I have tried all kinds of routing setup on the server, I have tried to follow the guide here: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System - but my setup is slightly different, since I dont have a default gateway in the 192.168.1.0/24 net.

The 10Gb networks is a new addition, before adding those, everyhing was peachy - I added the 10gb netcards to get a fast connection to the server so I could mount iscsi on a fast low latency connection.

I hope you bright people have good ideas.

Thanks
Bjørn

```
                                  Internet
                                     |
                                     |
                                     |
                                     |
                                     |
                                     |
                                     |
                            --------------------
                            |                  |
                ------------| Router/Switch    |-----------
                |           |  192.168.0.1     |          |
                |           --------------------          |
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
      Network Card 1 (ens192)                     Network Card 1 (eth0)
                |                                         |
       192.168.0.200 (s)                           192.168.0.29 (d)
      --------------------                      ---------------------
      |                  |                      |                   |
      |     Server 1     |                      |  Windows client   |
      |                  |                      |                   |
      --------------------                      ---------------------
         192.168.1.200 (s)                         192.168.1.49 (s)
      |                                         |
      Network Card 2 (ens161)                     Network Card 2 (eth1)
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                |               Direct 10GbE              |
                -------------------------------------------
```

## /etc/network/interfaces

```
    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    auto ens192
    iface ens192 inet static
    address 192.168.0.200
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.201
    dns-domain smith.local
    dns-domain cloud.local


    auto ens161
    iface ens161 inet static
        address 192.168.1.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0

        # fast interface route
        post-up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ens161 src 192.168.1.200 table rt2
        post-up ip route add default 192.168.1.49 dev ens161 table rt2

        post-up ip rule add from 192.168.1.200/32 table rt2
        post-up ip rule add to 192.168.1.200/32 table rt2
```

## route -n

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens192
    192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens192
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens161
```

## ip rule show

```
    0:      from all lookup local
    32764:  from all to 192.168.1.200 lookup rt2
    32765:  from 192.168.1.200 lookup rt2
    32766:  from all lookup main
    32767:  from all lookup default
```

## ip route list table rt2

```
192.168.1.0/24 dev ens161  scope link  src 192.168.1.200
```

## ip route list table main

```
    default via 192.168.0.1 dev ens192 onlink
    192.168.0.0/24 dev ens192  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.200
    192.168.1.0/24 dev ens161  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.200
```

Comment: You shouldn't need _any_ routing for a direct connection / local subnet - routing is only for getting out of the subnet.

Comment: If you physically disconnect the old 192.168.0.0/24 network, can you communicate over the new 192.168.1.0/24 direct connection? Linux implements the "[_weak host model_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model)" meaning that you could get a response from it's 192.168.1.200 interface via the physical 102.168.0.200 interface...

Comment: Both machines can already communicate over the 192.168.1.0/24 network, just not over the old network, which is my real problem. If I disconnect the cable from the windows pc, i.e. old network (192.168.0.0/24) - then I can also communicate on the new network

Comment: I've used a similar setup (albeit with only GigE) and had no issues. You shouldn't need a default gateway on either of the NICs that are directly connected, only on the one that connects to the router/switch. Anything that's in one of the 192.168.x.x subnets should automatically use the appropriate NIC and anything else should go to the default gateway via the NIC that's in the same subnet as it.

Comment: If you unplug the cable that goes directly from one computer to the other does everything work as it did previously?

Comment: Yes. I have two ping windows going on my machine while I try different settings on the ubuntu server. When I unplug the 10gb link, then the 192.168.0.0/24 net starts responding and the other naturally times out. and vice versa, as soon as I plug it back in, it stops responding

Comment: I am not sure if it makes any difference. The ubuntu server is a virtual machine on another physical machine (esxi) - both network cards are connected to the same virtual switch on esxi (since I could not figure out how to configure a network card to use a different virtual switch)

Comment: It works :-)
Turns out I am just a butthole :-)
I managed to make another virtual switch in esxi, put the 10gb card over there and move the virtual netcard to that switch and when I started the server again, everything just worked.
Let this be a lesson for all, different physical networks must be on different virtual switches in esxi.

Comment: "_The ubuntu server is a virtual machine_" / "_both network cards are connected to the same virtual switch on esxi_" - yes these matter! try to describe the problem in full :-)

Answer (score 0):

I digged more into why I could not create another virtual switch and found out that you are supposed to be able to, so I managed to make another virtual switch in esxi, put the 10gb card over there and move the virtual netcard to that switch and when I started the server again, everything just worked.

Let this be a lesson for all, different physical networks must be on different virtual switches in esxi.

So in reality there was no problem at all, this was in reality a esxi problem and not a linux problem. Linux was sending the packages correctly, but esxi was dropping them apparently.